# Complexity Class Equalities on the Edge of Inconsistency

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, circuit-complexity

What are some of the most extreme potential equalities between computational complexity classes (especially if there is a barrier to refuting them)?  These may give us an opportunity to prove better bounds, or provide a clearer understanding of the fundamental obstacles in complexity theory.

Here is my list (at most one and probably zero equalities actually hold):
* uniform TC<sup>0</sup> = NP
* NC<sup>1</sup> = CH (defined using logtime uniformity; implies NC<sup>1</sup> = LOGSPACE = PP)
* P = PSPACE
* ZPP = EXP = ⊕EXP
* BPP = NEXP = EXP<sup>NP</sup>

It remains open whether P=PSPACE can be combined with P having non-uniform TC<sup>0</sup>-circuits, which would allow P-uniform TC<sup>0</sup>-circuits for PSPACE, and analogously for ZPP/EXP and BPP/NEXP.  It is also open whether (logtime) uniform TC<sup>0</sup> with an additional random input can simulate EXP (with zero error and unlikely failure) or NEXP (with bounded error).  TC<sub>0</sub> < PP was only proved for (logtime) uniform TC<sup>0</sup> without randomness.  Also, if TC<sup>0</sup> is ruled out, we can fallback to NC<sup>1</sup> (with the same uniformity conditions).

More items:
* Uniform AC<sup>0</sup>[6]=PH has not yet been ruled out, but AC<sup>0</sup>[6] is arguably not a natural complexity class.
* P<sup>RP</sup> = NEXP
* P<sup>NP</sup> = ⊕P = PEXP (though this prevents P<sup>NP</sup> from being 'feasible')

*Quasilinear Time*

In the above, polynomial transformations of input size are immaterial, but the sharpened versions below care about the exact (up to a constant factor) size.

Sharpened version of P=PSPACE: Every function in nondeterministic linear space with linear output size can be computed in O(n*log n) time and O(n) space using a Turing machine with a single tape and a stack.  We can also ask for the machine to be reversible, and also oblivious with LOGSPACE computable movement.

Sharpened version of BPP=NEXP:  Every function (with linear output size) in E<sup>NP</sup> can be computed with linear size logarithmic depth bounded fan-in bounded fan-out uniform circuits, if O(n) random bits are appended to the input string, allowing 2<sup>-O(n)</sup> error probability.
*Notes:*
* This is arguably the most extreme equality that we cannot yet rule out.
* There are different notions of (essentially logtime) uniformity that allow quasilinear-time circuit construction, with one reasonable choice being a Time(O(log n * (log log n)<sup>O(1)</sup>)) algorithm that given gate number (perhaps with gate ordering consistent with causality) gives the type of gate and the numbers where to send the output.
* One can also ask about zero error, 2<sup>-O(n)</sup> failure probability, and functions in E (but not simultaneously with BPP=NEXP).
* If linear size logarithmic depth circuits are finally ruled out, we can backtrack to logarithmic time on uniform linear size O(1)-depth recurrent circuits (even with reversibility, and bounded fan-in and fan-out).
* Also, uniform TC<sup>0</sup> of size O(n<sup>1+ε</sup>) (with randomness as above; depth depends on ε) has not been ruled out.

Comment: The first entry on your list can be made more extreme in several ways, such as $\mathrm{AC}^0[6]=\mathrm{PH}$ or $\mathrm{NC}^1=\mathrm{CH}$. The latter is also more extreme than your second line.

Comment: http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/08/extreme-oracles.html may give you some ideas.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks.  I strengthened the first two entries accordingly, and added two entries from the link.

Comment: P-uniform NC$^1$ ​ = ​ PSPACE ​ ​ ​ is more extreme than ​ P = PSPACE . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thanks.  I added it to the list (and also added possible ZPP-uniform NC$^1$ = EXP).

Comment: The issue there is that for circuits, there are lots of different ways that ZPP-uniformity and BPP-uniformity could be defined. ​ ​

Comment: AFAIK, we cannot rule out uniform-$TC^0=NEXP$. i.e. poly-time-constructable constant-depth threshold circuits compute all of nodeterministic exponential time.

Comment: @RickyDemer Regardless of whether the circuit can depend on randomness, existence of ZPP-uniform  $\mathrm{NC}^1$ circuits for EXP is equivalent to ZPP=EXP plus existence of non-uniform $\mathrm{NC}^1$ circuits for EXP, and similarly for BPP=NEXP.  I revised the wording accordingly.  Incidentally, were P-uniform TC$^0$ circuits for PSPACE ruled out? The proof for uniform TC$^0$ < PP used logtime uniformity.

Comment: @Thomas P-uniform TC$^0$ is in P and so is not NEXP complete.  I am not sure whether that applies to uniform TC$^0$ circuits with randomness and bounded error.

Comment: You are too cool!  I'm digging this.  I added you on LinkedIn btw.  Hope that you have a lovely day!  :)